# printf statement inside the if condition

Tags: c, printf

Can anyone explain how does this work the output is A3 but how come it print 3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    if(printf("A"))
        i=3;
    else
        i=5;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check the flow:

```
    int i;            --> i has indeterminate value
    if(printf("A"))   --> prints A and returns 1, so the condition is TRUE (see note)
        i=3;          --> This statement is executed
    else              --> this condition is skipped
        i=5;          --> so this does not execute
    printf("%d",i);   --> prints the value of i which is 3.
```

Final print is `A3`.

That said, if no conversion specification is needed, instead of using `printf()`, one should use [`puts()` or `fputs()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts).

Note:

From [man `printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> **Return value**
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

Answer (score 14):

[`printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) returns the number of characters upon success and negative values on failure.

Therefore, if `printf("A")` succeeds, it will return `1`.

In C, values other than `0` is treated as true, so `i=3;` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

the trick to understand this behav is [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) and the return val od `printf`

> returns the number of characters upon success and negative values on failure.
> this here:

```
if(printf("A"))
```

can be read as

```
int r = printf("A");// at this point r ==1

if(1) //this here is true so i is assigned to 3
```